# Expected value and Variance calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $f$ is an uniformly distributed random variable with parameters $-1,1$ and $g$ is a Poisson-distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda >0$. We assume that $f$ and $g$ are independent and for a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ we define the random variable $h:=f+C^g$. Now I want to calculate $\text{E}[h]$ and $\text{Var}[h]$.

We have $\text{E}[f]=0$, $\text{Var}[f]=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\text{E}[g]=\text{Var}[g]=\lambda$.

$$\text{E}[h]=\text{E}[C^g]$$

$$\text{Var}[h]=\text{E}[h^2]-\text{E}[h]^2=\text{E}[f^2]+2\text{E}[fC^g]+\text{E}[C^{2g}]-\text{E}[h]^2$$
How can I calculate $\text{E}[C^g]$?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: $$E(C^g)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C^nP(g=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C^n\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(C\lambda)^n}{n!}=\ldots$$

Comment: Did you just downvote this answer?

Comment: Ah OK, then some lurkers have an odd conception of their role on this site.

Comment: The values you provided are exact. Re hints, I already gave one, which is huge. Here is another one: you might want to check an introductory chapter on the independence of random variables, this would allow you to answer the question you asked in a comment now deleted about the independence of $f$ and $C^g$.

Comment: Right, so you can finish this?